# How do I install only mongodb-org-shell and not mongodb in alpine?

Tags: linux, mongodb, docker, alpine-linux

How can I install just a mongo client shell on docker alpine using which I can connect to mongodb on another server?
This is to reduce the size of my image.

Comment: if you search for mongodb alpine packages, you only have mongodb and mongodb-tools, shell package is not available on alpine.

Comment: I tried compiling mongodb in alpine. It gives the option of compiling only `mongo`. But was not successful.

Answer (score -4):

To run a shell session:

```
$ docker exec -ti mongo sh
To use the mongo shell client:

$ docker exec -ti mongo mongo
The mongo shell client can also be run its own container:

$ docker run -ti --rm --name mongoshell mongo host:port/db
```

Comment: This answer is for xenial instead of alpine.